# An error occurred during the initialize Volo.Abp.Modularity.OnApplicationInitializationModuleLifecycleContributo

Tags: c#, openid, abp

when i create new project anglar and run the app i get this err

> An error occurred during the initialize Volo.Abp.Modularity.OnApplicationInitializationModuleLifecycleContributor phase of the module Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.AbpOpenIddictDomainModule, Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.Domain, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: An exception was thrown while activating Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.Tokens.TokenCleanupBackgroundWorker -> Volo.Abp.DistributedLocking.MedallionAbpDistributedLock.. See the inner exception for details.
> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.Tokens.TokenCleanupBackgroundWorker -> Volo.Abp.DistributedLocking.MedallionAbpDistributedLock.
> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Volo.Abp.DistributedLocking.MedallionAbpDistributedLock' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
> Cannot resolve parameter 'Medallion.Threading.IDistributedLockProvider distributedLockProvider' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Medallion.Threading.IDistributedLockProvider, Volo.Abp.Threading.ICancellationTokenProvider, Volo.Abp.DistributedLocking.IDistributedLockKeyNormalizer)'.

```
                                                           v
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure  you are running Redis. `DistributedLocking` refers to Redis in your error.

Comment: But i already stop it in settings

Comment: It doesn't matter you disable or not in appsettings. If you are using separated auth-server angular template, redis is a requirement. You can check the docs for more information: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Getting-Started-Setup-Environment?UI=NG&DB=EF&Tiered=Yes